# Sum values with Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wonder how to sum values using Python dictionary. I read huge file line by line and increment value for each particular key. Suppose I have the following toy file:

```
word1 5
word2 3
word3 1
word1 2
word2 1
```

The desired result I expected is:

```
my_dict = {'word1':7, 'word2':4, 'word3':1}
```

Pasted below is my current work.

```
my_dict = {}          
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.split()
        word = line[0]
        frequency = line[1]
        my_dict[word] += int(frequency)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

my_dict = Counter()

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        word, freq = line.split()
        my_dict[word] += int(freq)
```

Note that `str.rstrip()` is not needed, the `str.split()` call with no arguments *also* strips the string.

Apart from defaulting non-existing keys to 0, `Counter()` objects have additional advantages, such as listing words ordered by frequency (including a top N), summing and subtracting.

The above code results in:

```
>>> my_dict
Counter({'word1': 7, 'word2': 4, 'word3': 1})
>>> for word, freq in my_dict.most_common():
...     print word, freq
... 
word1 7
word2 4
word3 1
```

Comment: HI Martijn Pieters, I am trying to implement your code with a similiar problem, except there are 3 columns and the 4th column is the freq. to be summed. The error I am getting is: `  File "count.py", line 8, in <module>
    word, freq = line.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack
` any suggestions how to solve that?

Comment: @owwoow14: `line.split()` returns as many elements as there are on the line. Use the same number of variable names to assign *to* on the left-hand side of the `=` assignment: `word, othervalue, thirdvalue, freq = line.split()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        temp = row.split()
        d[temp[0]] += int(temp[1])
```

`d` is now:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'word1': 7, 'word3': 1, 'word2': 4})
```

Answer (score 0):

IN case someone is working with multiple columns (in my case I had the same problem but with 4 columns):

This should do the trick:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(int)

with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            items = line.split()
            freq = items[-1]
            lemma = tuple(items[:-1]) 

            my_dict[lemma] += int(freq)

for items, freq in my_dict.items():
    print items, freq
```